# Require certain specialization of template as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization, type-traits

I have a datastructure `meta_array` which is instantiated with a variant as type T parameter. The requirement is that the std::variant specialization must contain the type `meta_array_head_t` as this is is used for tracking information. Can I somehow state this as a requirement using type traits (C++17)?

[CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:18,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:18,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Astruct+meta_array_head_t+%7B%0A++++//+end_%3B%0A++++//+remaining_%3B%0A++++//+prev_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+size_t+S%3E%0Astruct+meta_array%0A%7B%0A++++std::array%3CT,+S%3E+data_%3B+%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Ausing+val+%3D+std::variant%3Cstd::monostate,+int,+double,+meta_array_head_t%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++meta_array%3Cval,+100%3E+marray%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <variant>
#include <array>

struct meta_array_head_t {
    // end_;
    // remaining_;
    // prev_;
};

template <typename T, size_t S> // make sure T = std::variant<... , meta_array_head_t, ...>
struct meta_array
{
    std::array<T, S> data_; 
};


using val = std::variant<std::monostate, int, double, meta_array_head_t>;

int main()
{
    meta_array<val, 100> marray;
}
```

Comment: T can only be a `std::variant` ? Would it be ok to append `meta_array_head_t` to the variant when not present rather than requiring the user to include it ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I thought of this as well but unfortunately variants don't support set theory (intersection of two variants containing partially the same type), and access is performed elsewhere through  a common `using` declaration. So when I include `meta_array_head_t` it would change the type and result in errors

Comment: it was just my first idea. You can check if the type is present and add it if not, thats possible, but not any simpler than your current approach. Perhaps a little user friendly. Currently you allow the user to make a mistake, they can use a variant without the `meta_array_head_t` just to get an error. On the other hand, implicitly adding it might also be confusing

Answer (score 5):

First, determine that `T` is of type `std::variant`, then use fold expression to detect whether the alternative type contains `meta_array_head_t`.

```
#include <variant>

template<typename T>
struct meta_variant : std::false_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct meta_variant<std::variant<Ts...>> : 
  std::bool_constant<((std::is_same_v<Ts, meta_array_head_t> || ...))> { };

template <typename T, size_t>
struct meta_array {
  static_assert(meta_variant<T>::value, 
    "T must be a std::variant specialization "
    "containing an alternative type of meta_array_head_t.");
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qors6YsT6)

Comment: Why did you enclose the fold expression into double parenthesis? Although usually fold expressions need a lot of them, in this case one pair would be sufficient I believe..

Comment: @JakobStark I don't know, my brain made me do this unconsciously.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::disjunction_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) instead of fold expression for short-circuiting.

Based on @康桓瑋's answer.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct meta_variant : std::false_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct meta_variant<std::variant<Ts...>> {
      static constexpr bool value = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Ts, meta_array_head_t>...>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9WEoM4d1n)

Comment: Cool, I'm learning a new type_trait every day. You could also derive this from bool_constant to keep it even consiser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specialization to write the trait. Rather than allowing the user to make the mistake and only produce an error you could add the type to the variant when it isnt present:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

struct foo {};

template <typename T>
struct has_foo_as_variant : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct has_foo_as_variant<std::variant<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = (std::is_same_v<Ts,foo> || ...);
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_foo_as_variant_v = has_foo_as_variant<T>::value;

template <typename T>
struct variant_with_foo;

template <typename...Ts>
struct variant_with_foo< std::variant<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::conditional_t< has_foo_as_variant_v<std::variant<Ts...>>,
                                    std::variant<Ts...>,
                                    std::variant<foo,Ts...>>;
};

int main() {
    using good_t = std::variant<foo,int,double>;
    using bad_t = std::variant<int,double>;
    std::cout << has_foo_as_variant_v<good_t>;
    std::cout << has_foo_as_variant_v<bad_t>;
    using foo_added_t = typename variant_with_foo<bad_t>::type;
    std::cout << has_foo_as_variant_v<foo_added_t>;
}
```